# I have problems with the mantaflow fire simulation. The fire is visible through other objects if I use the render engine eevee or the material preview

Tags: eevee-render-engine, fire, mantaflow

Hey I have problems with the mantaflow fire simulation. For some reason, the fire is visible through other objects. This happens only in material preview and if I use the render engine eevee. In Cycles or solid mode, the fire doesn't emit in this way through other meshs: it's hidden as expected behind the objects.

Because I want to make an film, I can't use the option "starting point" under the volumetric setting to hide the effect. At least that is how it seems to me.

In the last few hours I tried to be lucky and tried different settings. Nothing helped. The different tutorials I have seen did not address this problem in any form (from my point view and knowledge).

In the screenshots I used 32. But 128 didn't solve the issue.

[image].
[image]

The Blend mode of the objects is set to opaque, which seems to be the right setting.[image]

The firebowl is set to collosion
[image]